# How do I declare the objects related to one class in other?

Tags: c++, class, oop, variables, inner-classes

The error shows: `no matching functions for call to birthday::birthday()`. How else should I declare the objects of one class in another class?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class birthday
{

public:

    birthday(int d,int m,int y)
    {
        date=d;
        month=m;
        year=y;
    }
    void printdate()
    {
        cout<<date<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
    }

private:

    int date;
    int month;
    int year;
};

class person
{

public:

    person(string x)
    {
        name=x;
    }
    void printname()
    {
        cout<< "the birthday person is "<< name << " whose birthday is on "<< day.printdate();
    }

private:

    birthday day;
    string name;
};

int main()
{
   birthday b(10,11,2007);
   person p("Jessica");
   p.printname();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: When a `person` is constructed, what do you want `birthday day` to hold?  Currently, a `birthday` can not be created without supplying a day, month, and year.

Comment: Unless you modify `birthday` so that there is a constructor that can be called with 0 arguments, you need to use the initializer list to pass the constructor arguments or add a default initialization: `person(string x): day(1, 1, 1970), name(std::move(x)) {}` or `birthday day { 1, 1, 1970};`

Answer (score 2):

Just define a **default constructor** so you can make an object of type `birthday` without initializing it.

or  you can default initialize `person` type private data member `day`.

Answer (score 2):

While the answers given regarding adding a default c'tor for `birthday` are technically correct, I think that they miss the real issue. Given how you declare the variables `b` and `p` in `main()`, it looks as if your intent is for the `birthday` variable `b` to be added to the `person` variable, which implies that what you actually want is to modify the `person()` constructor as such:

```
    person(string x, birthday b): name(x), day(b)
    { }
```

This will ensure that a `birthday` object is defined for a given `person` object when the `person` is constructed.

This isn't to say that adding a default c'tor for either `birthday` or `person` is wrong; indeed, it would probably be advisable. But on its own it might not have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that your class `birthday` has a user-defined constructor and therefore the compiler will not synthesize the default constructor `birthday::birthday()` for your class.

So when you wrote,

```
class person
{
    //other members here
    private:
         birthday day; //this need the default constructor of birthday. But since class birthday has no default constructor this statement gives error
};
```

In the above snippet, the statetment, `birthday day;` needs the **default constructor** of class `birthday` but since there isn't one, so this statement results in the mentioned error.

##### Solution

To solve this you can add a default constructor for your class birthday as shown below:

```
class birthday
{

public:
    //add default constructor
    birthday() = default;
    birthday(int d,int m,int y)
    {
        date=d;
        month=m;
        year=y;
    }
    void printdate()
    {
        cout<<date<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
    }

private:

    //using in class initializers give some default values to the data members according to your needs
    int date = 0;
    int month =0;
    int year = 0;
};

class person
{

public:

    
    person(string x)
    {
        name=x;
    }
    void printname()
    {
        cout<< "the birthday person is "<< name << " whose birthday is on "; 
        
        day.printdate();//moved this out of the cout because printdat() does not return anything
    }

private:

    birthday day;
    string name;
};

int main()
{
   birthday b(10,11,2007);
   person p("Jessica");
   p.printname();
   return 0;
}
```

Some of the changes that i made include:

1. Added default constructor for class `birthday`.
2. Used **in-class initializers** for data member `date`, `year` and `month` inside class `birthday`.
3. There was another problem with your code. Originally you had a statement `cout<<day.printdate()` in your program. But since `printdate()` has return type `void`, so the statement `cout<<day.printdate()` will give you error. To solve this, i removed the `cout` from this statement.

The output of the modified program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/aF58Zi2xN).